# org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped

Tags: java, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I just changed from cxf-codegen-plugin 3.5.3 to 4.0.0. Now I get this warning:

```
[WARNING] mars 09, 2023 10:17:25 FM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder checkForWrapped
[WARNING] INFO: Operation {http://soa.jboss.org/print}sendEmail-2.0Op cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localname as operation
```

What impact does it have?

If necessary, how do I solve it?

This is the wsdl:

```
<wsdl:message name="sendEmail-2.0Res">
    <wsdl:part element="esbns2:sendEmailResponse" name="out">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sendEmail-2.0Fault1">
    <wsdl:part element="esbns3:fikFault" name="fault1">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sendEmail-2.0Req">
    <wsdl:part element="esbns1:sendEmailRequest" name="in">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="sendEmail-2.0PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="sendEmail-2.0Op">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:sendEmail-2.0Req" name="sendEmail-2.0Req">
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:sendEmail-2.0Res" name="sendEmail-2.0Res">
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:sendEmail-2.0Fault1" name="fault1">
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="sendEmail-2.0Binding" type="tns:sendEmail-2.0PortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sendEmail-2.0Op">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://soa.jboss.org/sendEmail-2.0/sendEmail-2.0OpResp"/>
        <wsdl:input name="sendEmail-2.0Req">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="sendEmail-2.0Res">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
            <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="sendEmail-2.0Service">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:sendEmail-2.0Binding" name="sendEmail-2.0PortType">
        <soap:address location="url"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```